# Vue.js - How to get and set a value of a component input field?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just started learning Vue.js but I ran into a problem where I can't figure out how I could access and change a text field value that is inside my component.

Let's say I would like to access or change the value of my first input field that is inside my  component

**My component**

```
Vue.component('simple-input',
{
    template: `
        <input type="text" value="Some value...">
    `,
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="root">
  <simple-input></simple-input>
  <simple-input></simple-input>
  <simple-input></simple-input>

  <div @click="alertSimpleInput1">Show first input value</div>
  <div @click="changeInput1('new value')">Change input value</div>

  <div @click="alertSimpleInput2">Show second input value</div>
</div>
```

**main.js**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#root',
});
```

Comment: You can use v-model to achieve exactly what you want. [see here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having `value="Some value..."` in your template means that the input's value will be set to the string "Some value..." initially. You need to *bind* the input's value to a data property on the component. Use [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) for a two-way binding (when the input value changes, it will update the value of the data property and vice versa).

In your example there's actually a bit more involved though since you want to obtain the input's value from the root component, therefore the `<simple-input>` component must expose this; the way to do this is by using *props* (for parent-to-child data flow) and *events* (for child-to-parent data flow).

Untested:

```js
Vue.component('simple-input', {
  template: `
    <input type="text" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
  `,
  props: ['value'],
});
```

```vue
<div id="root">
  <simple-input v-model="value1"></simple-input>
  <simple-input v-model="value2"></simple-input>
  <simple-input v-model="value3"></simple-input>

  <button @click="alertSimpleInput1">Show first input value</button>
  <button @click="changeInput1('new value')">Change input value</button>
  <button @click="alertSimpleInput2">Show second input value</button>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  
  data: {
    value1: 'Initial value 1',
    value2: 'Initial value 2',
    value3: 'Initial value 3',
  },

  methods: {
    alertSimpleInput1() {
      alert(this.value1);
    },

    alertSimpleInput2() {
      alert(this.value2);
    },

    changeInput1(newValue) {
      this.value1 = newValue;
    },
  },
});
```

I understand you're just learning Vue, but there's a lot to unpack here for a beginner. I won't go into detail because there's lots of information about these concepts already.

Read the following:

- [Component Basics](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)
- [Using `v-model` on Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) (for an explanation of the `<simple-input>` code)

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Although I still don't understand everything how it works. Is it possible to have 2 input fields in my template and bind the value for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  $emit method for this purpose.

```
<simple-input @clicked="inputValue" :name="name"></simple-input>

parent methods

export default {

 data: function () {
    return {
       name:null
    }
  },
  methods: {
   inputValue (value) {
    console.log(value) // get input value
   }
 }
}
  Vue.component('simple-input', {
  data: function () {
    return {
       // name:null
    }
  },
  watch:{
    'name':function(){
        this.$emit('clicked', this.name)
    }
   template: '<input type="text" v-model="name">'
   props:['name']
})
```